# How to use a crate with a hyphen (-) in the name?

Tags: rust, rust-crates

[This crate's](https://github.com/sdroege/rtsp-types) name is:

```
name = "rtsp-types"
```

How can I use it on my project?

I added to the `Cargo.toml`:

```
[dependencies]
rtsp-types = { path = "../rtsp-types" }
```

however I can't do

```rust
use rtsp-types
```

because of the `-` symbol.

Comment: `use rtsp_types`.

Comment: *modules* are a distinct concept from *crates*. Searching for the correct term likely will give you better results.

Comment: A lot of crates have a dash-underscore identity crisis.

Comment: @Shepmaster 3 | mod rtsp_types;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = help: to create the module `rtsp_types`, create file "src/rtsp_types.rs"

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `Method` in `rtsp_types`

Comment: Yes, that's because `mod` is not the same as `use`, which is what I suggested that you do.